# Change a list to a string with specific formatting

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Let's say that I have a list of names:

```
names = ['john', 'george', 'ringo', 'paul']
```

And need to get a string output like:

```
john', 'george', 'ringo', 'paul
```

(Note that the missing quote at the beginning and at the end is on purpose)

Is there an easier way to do this than

```
new_string=''
for x in names:
    new_string = new_string + x + "', '"
```

I know something like that will work, however the real `names` list will be very very (very) big and was wondering if there is a nicer way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> names = ['john', 'george', 'ringo', 'paul']
>>> print("', '".join(names))
john', 'george', 'ringo', 'paul
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be bad way to do it, just wana share it :

```
>>> names = ['john', 'george', 'ringo', 'paul']
>>> print(str(names)[2:-2])
john', 'george', 'ringo', 'paul
```